# from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials ImportError: No module named appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We are trying to import AppAssertionCredentials from oauth2client. We are using python27 standard google app engine.

Our appengine_config.py is as follows

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

The import statement in one of our modules is this.

```
 # from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
 import httplib2
 from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
 from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
```

We checked the "lib" folder in our application. It has oauth2client in it. It also has contrib which has the appengine.py file. We did the following to install our requirements.

```
google-endpoints==4.8.0
google-endpoints-api-management==1.11.0
apiclient
firebase_admin
sendgrid==5.2.0
google.auth
jinja2
pytz
stripe
twilio
httplib2
oauth2client==3.0.0
GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient
```

For some reason when we execute endpointscfg.py it is throwing this error. The endpointscfg.py is from [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/endpoints_tool).
        from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials ImportError: No module named appengine

Updated

Our app.yaml is as follows -

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 100
  min_pending_latency: 30ms  # default value
  max_pending_latency: automatic

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest  
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: 2.6
- name: PIL
  version: 1.1.7
- name: ssl
  version: 2.7.11


inbound_services:
- channel_presence

handlers:

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /javascripts
  static_dir: javascripts

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  application_readable: true 


- url: /sakthihemaadmin
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /sakthihemaadmindisplay
  script: main.app  

- url: /signup
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /login
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /forgot
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /initprogram
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /debugprogram
  script: main.app
  secure: always


# Endpoints handler: this must be /_ah/spi for Endpoints, NOT /_ah/api!
- url: /_ah/api/.*
  # script: cloudendpointapi.APPLICATION
  script: main.api

# Required for deferred 
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
  login: admin


- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

We are not creating OpenAPI document but rather creating the client libraries as listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/endpoints_tool#generating_an_openapi_document_from_an_api).

```
 endpointscfg.py get_discovery_doc
```

Comment: *Update: link was not correct*. Can you please provide an example of how you're executing the following command when [generating an OpenAPI document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/endpoints_tool#generating_an_openapi_document_from_an_api). What does your app.yaml look like?

Comment: Resolved this by using $ lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py instead of endpointscfg.py

Comment: @Jacktileman Please post the solution as an answer, that will be helpful for the community

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using endpointscfg.py get_discovery_doc please use $ lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py .

I guess there was another version of endpointscfg.py in my environment that was causing the issue.

This helped me resolve the issue.